# Will .exceptionally() catch exceptions thrown from within nested futures? Or where is correct to put .exceptionally()

Tags: java, exception, java-8, future, completable-future

```
foo.thenCompose(fooResponse -> {
  ...
  return bar.thenCompose(barResponse -> {
    ...
  });
}).exceptionally(e -> {
  ...
});
```

Will this `.exceptionally()` also catch exceptions thrown from within the nested `bar.thenCompose` lambda? Or do I need to write this:

```
foo.thenCompose(fooResponse -> {
  ...
  return bar.thenCompose(barResponse -> {
    ...
  }).exceptionally(nestedE -> {
    ...
  });
}).exceptionally(e -> {
  ...
});
```

Then rethrow up?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @JacobG. - Yup, colleague is. Throwing a question up to self-answer once we find out. I couldn't find a question that answered this, the way I was wording it. Probably someone here can give more insights about it though, regardless.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll take a shot in a couple hours if it still isn't answered.

Comment: So the answer is Yes, it did catch it. But, my intuition was saying, syntactically, it seems each chain of `.thenApply()`, `.thenCompose()`, etc. should end with its own `.exceptionally()`. Hm... Is it maybe that, since the nested call is returning a future, which gets chained to the rest of the outside calls, in effect it's all really just a single chain of futures? Maybe that's the intuition I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single `exceptionally` at the end is sufficient to replace any throwable with an alternative ordinary result value, at least for the resulting stage returned by it, but it’s worth cleaning up the mind set that led to this question.

`exceptionally` does not *catch* any exceptions and there are no *nested* futures either. It’s important to understand that all methods defined by [`CompletionStage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) create a *new* completion stage whose completion will be affected by the contract of the particular method, but never affect the completion stage, the method has been invoked on.

So when you use `exceptionally`, there are two futures involved, the one you’re invoking exceptionally on and the new future returned by `exceptionally`. The contract is that the latter will be completed with the same value as the former, in case of an ordinary completion, but with the result of the function evaluation, if the former has been completed exceptionally.

So when you execute

```
for(int run = 0; run < 4; run++) {
    CompletableFuture<String> stage1 = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<String> stage2 = stage1.exceptionally(t -> "alternative result");

    if(run > 1) stage2.cancel(false);

    if((run&1) == 0) stage1.complete("ordinary result");
    else stage1.completeExceptionally(new IllegalStateException("some failure"));

    stage1.whenComplete((v,t) ->
        System.out.println("stage1: "+(t!=null? "failure "+t: "value "+v)));
    stage2.whenComplete((v,t) ->
        System.out.println("stage2: "+(t!=null? "failure "+t: "value "+v)));
    System.out.println();
}
```

it will print:

```
stage1: value ordinary result
stage2: value ordinary result

stage1: failure java.lang.IllegalStateException: some failure
stage2: value alternative result

stage1: value ordinary result
stage2: failure java.util.concurrent.CancellationException

stage1: failure java.lang.IllegalStateException: some failure
stage2: failure java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
```

showing that the first stage always reflects the result of our explicit completion, regardless of what happens to the second stage. So `exceptionally` doesn’t catch the exception, the exceptional completion of the previous stage never changes, all it does, is to define the completion of a new stage.

So if `stage1` was the result of, say `stage0.thenCompose(x -> someOtherStage)` call, it doesn’t matter to the relationship between `stage1` and `stage2`. All that matters, is the completion of `stage1`.

1. If `stage0` gets completed exceptionally, it will attempt to complete `stage1` exceptionally
2. If `stage0` gets completed with a value and the function throws an exception, it will attempt to complete `stage1` exceptionally
3. If `stage0` gets completed with a value and the function return a stage (`someOtherStage`) that has been or will be completed exceptionally, it will attempt to complete `stage1` exceptionally
4. If `stage0` gets completed with a value and the function return a stage (`someOtherStage`) that has been or will be completed with a value, it will attempt to complete `stage1` with that value

Note that there is no nesting, `someOtherStage` might be a newly constructed or an already existing stage and it might be used at other places as well. Since the chaining always constructs new stages not affecting the existing ones, these other places would not be affected by anything happening here.

Note further the term “attempt to complete”, as we still could invoke `complete`, `completeExceptionally`, or `cancel` on `stage1` before that attempt. To the `stage2`, it doesn’t matter which way the completion happened, all that matters, is the result.

So if the attempts of any of the cases from 1. to 3., to complete `stage1` exceptionally, succeed, there will be an attempt to complete `stage2` with the result of the function passed to `exceptionally`. In case 4, if the attempt to complete `stage1` with a value succeeds, there will be an attempt to complete `stage2` with that value.

To demonstrate the irrelevance of the previous stage’s history, if we use

```
CompletableFuture<String> stage1 = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<String> stage2 = stage1.thenCompose(s -> new CompletableFuture<>());
CompletableFuture<String> stage3 = stage2.exceptionally(t -> "alternative result");

stage1.complete("ordinary result"); // you can omit this line if you want
stage2.completeExceptionally(new IllegalStateException("some failure"));

stage3.whenComplete((v,t) ->
    System.out.println("stage3: "+(t!=null? "failure "+t: "value "+v)));
```

It will print `stage3: value alternative result` due to the fact that `stage2` has been complete exceptionally, the history of the completion being entirely irrelevant. The `stage1.complete("ordinary result");` statement will cause the evaluation of the function returning a new `CompletableFuture` that will never be completed, hence not contribute to the result. If we omit this line, `stage1` will never be completed and the function never be evaluated, hence, the “nested” stage will never be created, but as said, this history doesn’t matter to the `stage2`.

So if your last invocation of chaining completion stages is an `exceptionally(function)`, it will return a new stage that will always be completed with a value, either from the previous stage or returned from the `function`, regardless of how the dependency graph before them looks like. Unless `function` itself throws an exception or someone invokes one of the explicit completion methods on it, like `cancel`.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. This was so helpful to resetting my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via 'exceptionally' method you can handle nested CompletableFuture 
The first example will be working